# Using Apache to serve Django project on RHEL (503 error)

Tags: django, apache, port, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-503

I am a newbie to the whole website thing... Would really appreciate if you could give some help here...

What I want to do is host a Django project on a remote server (red hat, CentOS release 6.5)

I've been running test of the project on a remote server using the development server and port 8000:

```
  python manage.py runserver *.*.*.*:8000 --insecure
```

In this case, the website works fine and accessible from other machines.

```
   0 errors found
   September 04, 2014 - 08:13:03
   Django version 1.6.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
   Starting development server at http://*.*.*.*:8000/
   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Now I want to put it in production, and I've chosen to use Apache http server and mod_wsgi. I have httpd and wsgi installed and activated. I changed the httpd.conf configuration file to:

```
   Listen *:80 (I've also tried Listen *:8000 and Listen (IP address):8000)

   #DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
   DocumentRoot "/testsite"      (I put a plan html file under the directory just for test)

   ServerName <here is the url of the site,with no port number>
```

However, when I try to open the webpage I am always having a 503 error:

```
   Service Temporarily Unavailable

   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime 
   or capacity problems. Please try again later.

   Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at <site url> Port 80
```

I tried a couple of things (1) checked what's using the port 80:

```
  ~# sudo lsof -i :80
  COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
  httpd   28732   root    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28734 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28735 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28736 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28737 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28738 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28739 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28740 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  httpd   28741 apache    4u  IPv6 19802111      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
  ~# service httpd status
  httpd (pid  28732) is running...
```

(2) restart the apache server:

```
  service httpd restart
    Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
    Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

(3) placed a plain .html in /var/www/html/testsite, the DocumentRoot directory for testing.

(4) I tried to run the django on a different port (such as 8008, 8001 and 80)

```
   e.g. python manage.py runserver *.*.*.*:8008 --insecure
   0 errors found
   September 04, 2014 - 07:56:18
   Django version 1.6.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
   Starting development server at http://*.*.*.*:8008/
   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

As shown above, in the terminal it looks like it's working , but I cannot even access the website from remote machines even using the development server. I tried different port numbers but only the port 8000 can be used. But why can I open the webpage on localhost when I change the port number? e.g. 127.0.0.1:8008 or 127.0.0.1:8080 will work.

I guess it can be the firewall setting, then I went to /etc/sysconfig/iptables, I found under the web section, there was only one line:

```
   -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I added another line for testing:

```
   -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT
```

Then tried the development again with port 8001. Again, it looks like it's woking on the remote server but not accessible from remote machines.

Sorry if I made this confusing and if I asked something really silly. Now, I have three questions that I really don't understand. First of all, the 503 error really annoys me. Even it shows the apache server is running (restart httpd is OK), nothing actually displays... Second of all, when using the development server why can I only use port 8000 but not any else? Finally, in the 503 error message, it shows apache runs on Port 80 even after I changed the Listen port to 8000 in the configuration file, why is this?

Thanks ahead for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If that is your only configuration I don't see how Apache could be aware of your Django running 8000. There is no indication that you are making Apache to connect or proxy requests to running Django instance.

What you need to do is

- [Configure mod_wsgi for Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

or

- [Configure fgci for Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/)

You are free to choose any port with Django development server. You can configure the IP address and the port the development server listens to with command line parameters.

You can make the Django development server to listen all IP addresses, including public IP addresses on the server, as:

```
 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Also Apache logs can be read at /var/log/apache (or similar directory), so it should explain why you are getting 503.

I doubt iptables are not related to any way to your problem, but somehow Django development server is not listening to public IP address. You can easily try this by disabled iptables firewall on the server.

Comment: The mod_wsgi and FASTCGI mechanisms are completely separate. You do not need to configure both and should choose just one. FASTCGI is though the least preferred option and mod_wsgi would usually be the better choice. The development server doesn't need to be running for either. Sorry, but found the answer confusing so thought I would clarify.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, Thanks! Added missing "or" word :)